# Capture does not work when used with several commands

Tags: stata

I have more than `3,000` variables and labels in my `do` file, but in my dataset I need `~300` of the labels. To bypass the errors of not having the variables, I used the `capture` command.

In my data, there are no `hhid` or `hh_cu_q` variables and there is only a `newid` variable:

```
capture noisily {
    label var hhid "Identifier for household with more than one CU. Household with only one CU will be set to missing."
    label var hh_cu_q "Count of Consumer Units in this household"
    label var newid "Public use microdata identifier"
}
```

However, when I run this code, I see the error for the first line of the command (variable `hhid` not found), and it seems that Stata is executing the rest of the lines, but there is no change in the label!

If I run only the last line of the command it works fine (it adds the label for `newid`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior because you are applying `capture` in an entire *block* of commands. As a result, when an error arises, Stata bypasses all remaining commands in the block and moves on to executing the rest of the `do` file.

When applying `capture` individually everything works as you expect:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate newid = .

. capture noisily label var hhid "Identifier for household with more than one CU. Household with only one CU will be set to missing."
variable hhid not found

. capture noisily label var hh_cu_q "Count of Consumer Units in this household"
variable hh_cu_q not found

. capture noisily label var newid "Public use microdata identifier"

. display "`: variable label newid'"
Public use microdata identifier
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine. In the help page there is a part that says we can apply `capture` over an entire block. Anyway, I added capture in the front of all lines. Thanks again!

Comment: Indeed; you can do it, and often it’s what is wanted, but not here.

Comment: @Parham Thanks for the accept. It is important to also up-vote with the upper arrow all helpful answers you see.